# Testing a method with yield using rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, yield

I have a method which yields. I am testing it for two conditions.

1) if it yields ( I am successfully able to do this using the yield match)

2) if it does not yield. ( This is where any help in the right direction would be appreciated.)

Method:

```
def example_method
  yield if block_given?
end
```

Specs:

```
it 'yields to a block' do
  expect{ |b| example_method(&b) }.to yield_with_no_args
end

it 'does not yield if a block is not given' do
end
```

The first spec passes successfully, but for the second spec I am not sure how to proceed, since the yield match would require a block to be given and if a block is given it would pass, whereas I want to test it for not yielding if a block is not given.

Thanks!

Comment: Here are latest docs on [Yield Matchers](https://rspec.info/features/3-12/rspec-expectations/built-in-matchers/yield/)

Answer (score 1):

Try something like

```
expect { example_method }.to_not yield_control
```

Comment: Worth linking to the documentation on [Yield Matchers](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/docs/built-in-matchers/yield-matchers) as there's some great examples there.

Comment: That was my initial approach, but when I try doing that I get an error which says :
"Your expect block must accept an argument to be used with this matcher. Pass the argument as a block on to the method you are testing."
If you go through the documentation for yield matcher even it specifies that a block must be passed.

Comment: and if you use the block what happens?

Comment: The test fails since, the method would yield to the block.

Comment: I'll try this, I'll let you know

Comment: Sorry man, you're right, this does not work because you need to pass a block :/ what I can suggest you is do an if block_given? call a method or another and test those two methods. in the one for the block not given you can do that `expect { block_given_false_method }.to_not yield_control` at that point

Comment: otherwise we need to know what your method does and test specifically in both cases